# Copyrights of material that would be used for both commercial and non-commercially

Tags: copyright, licensing

I want to include some audio materials in a mobile app that I am developing.

Those audio materials are "free to use or redistribute for **non-commercial use**". My app is free but I will put Ads. Furthermore, the mobile users can upgrade their account to premium (and pay fees) so they can listen and download more Audio materials monthly.

Am I allowed to include those materials in my app? 
Does the fact that I gain money from Ads or from premium users (which they have access to exactly the same materials but with bigger traffic) makes my case **commercial-use**?

Some clarifications:

1. I am not selling this content directly and will never claim the ownership of them. I will just put the content on a server (owned by me) and give access to my both free & premium users.
2. Those materials are already freely available on the owner website and on may other websites for free also.
3. If anyone is wondering why I did not just contact the owner, I did so many times without any luck of getting any answer.

Comment: What would the app be used to do? Something business related?

Comment: @ohwilleke No, the app would be used for users entertainment. You may consider it as a music playing app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course making money from it makes it commercial use.

Sometimes people use pre-written licenses that include language like that and if you do get a hold of the person who made the music they may have been using one of those pre-written licenses and not care if you use it, so try again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and suggestion!